# Phalcon PHP - Token not being read from Authorization Header in Postman

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, postman, phalcon

I have a Phalcon PHP application where I'm trying to implement token-based authentication. I have a method in my code like this:

```
public function infoAction()
{
$access_token = $this->request->getHeader('Authorization');
if (!$this->isLoggedIn($access_token)) {
return $this->unauthorized();
}
return $this->response->setJsonContent($this->getUserInfo());
}
```

When I register, I receive a token like this:

`eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoyNTZ9.v0cXrqoDEix-xCSVa8aFzNvyLW1monPv0lsaB8cj0Rc`

Now, I want to test the infoAction method in Postman. I'm adding the token I received during registration to the "Authorization" header in Postman with the key "Authorization," and I set the value to the token. However, after sending the request, it seems like the token parameters are not being read, and I'm not getting the expected result.

I'm looking for guidance on how to properly send and read the token in the "Authorization" header using Postman with my Phalcon PHP application.

[image: postman picture]

I even tried to put that token as Bearer token in the Authorization section, but the problem was still not solved

Comment: So are you saying that when you run `$access_token = $this->request->getHeader('Authorization');`, there is no value in the `$access_token` field? What does `var_dump($access_token);` show you?

Comment: I think, you need to delete word Bearer from header value and pass only token value